# Using an overlay view gestureRecognizer simultaneously with a MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, simultaneous, movieplayer

Currently I have a parent view with a gestureRecognizer on it, that recognises a tap and does some code (this works). There is a MoviePlayer inside a subview of this parent, and this now no longer recognises any gestures.

How can I get both to work simultaneously? I have found examples in objC, but can't seem to map this to **swift**. I've tried adding the following methods (as suggested in a post) but doesn't work.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
    gestureRecognizer_: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

My class extends UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, and the GestureRecognizer delegate is set to self.

Hierarchy:

```
ParentView -- Gesture
     |
      ------ MoviePlayer Sub View
```

Any ideas?

Regards